# How to use a condition inside Detail view widget in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, detailview

following is a detail view widget

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'name',
            'entity_name',
            'voucher_category',
            'credit',
            'debit',
            'remarks:ntext',
            'posting_date',
            'payment.method',

            [
            'label'  => 'Reference Date',
            'value' => $model->reference_date !=NULL  ?  $model->reference_date: 'Not Defined',
            ],
            'voucher_no',

        ],
    ]) ?>
```

what i want is to check that

```
                    if($model->voucher_category ==0)
                    {
                        return "Income Voucher";
                    }
                    elseif($model->voucher_category ==1)
                    {
                        return "Exepense Voucher";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         return "General Voucher"; 
                    }
```

ie, i want to check  a condition based on which a value should be displayed in the view. How can i do this in a detail view widget?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add condition using ternary. For Example,

```
[
 'attribute' => 'voucher_category',
 'value' => (($model->voucher_category ==0) ? "Income Voucher": (($model->voucher_category ==1)? "Exepense Voucher" : "General Voucher")),
],
```

Comment: i have used it already in my question. There is only two options here a Yes or a No. i have 3 conditions to check

Answer (score 1):

Incognito Skull's answer is great, but i have found another way to do it. With the help of function inside model.
Inside View

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
                 'id',

                 ...      

                 array(
                'format' => 'text',
                'value'=>$model->getvoucher(),
                'attribute'=>'voucher_category_id',
                ), 

        ],
    ]) ?>
```

Inside Model

```
                public function getvoucher()
                {
                 if($this->voucher_category ==0)
                    {
                        return "Income Voucher";
                    }
                    elseif($this->voucher_category ==1)
                    {
                        return "Exepense Voucher";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         return "General Voucher"; 
                    }
                  }
```

i don't know if this method is right or should be used, but you can do this to get the desired result. Personally i used Insane skull's answer.

Another way to do it

```
[
             'label' => 'Vocuher Category',

             'attribute' => function( $model )
             {
                if( $model->voucher_category == 0 )
                    return "Income Voucher";
                if( $model->voucher_category == 1 )
                    return "Expense Voucher";
                else
                    return "General Voucher";
             }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'title',
         [
         'attribute' => 'availability',
         'value' => (($model->availability ==1) ? "Available":'Not Available'),
         ],
      ],
    ]) ?>
```